# Maintaining a scroll position (scrollTop): Stutters when zooming in the latest Chrome. A bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm maintaining a scroll position in a web page as the browser changes the position automatically due to AJAX div updates. For some odd reason, the scrollTop() behaves differently in Chrome and scrolls to a wrong position.

```
var previousLocation = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns, for example, 240

// ....Update div with data from an AJAX call

$(window).scrollTop(previousLocation); // goes to 239 in Chrome instead of 240????
```

This works fine with all browsers when the zoom level is 100 %. However, other zoom levels such as 90% cause stuttering (scrolling goes a little bit up and down) in the latest Chrome (36.0.1985.143 m). Works, however, fine with the latest Firefox (31.0) and IE 11.

Any comments or similar results from anyone?

Comment: Perhaps! your scrolling pixels changes with zoom in or out. May be you should try `$(window).scrollTop(element of your last position);`